# udp poll sockets and multicast in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

1) I am trying to make a simple game server using UDP. Would my code be the   correct way to check if there is any reads from a single socket?

2) I want to recieve data from one user on a request ( he wants to move left), then update where the server thinks he or she is located, then broadcast the x , y coordinates. How would I implement a multicast reply with a different socket?

```
void run()
{
    //logging file
    ofstream log;
    log.open("server_log.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;      // our address 
    struct sockaddr_in remaddr;     // remote address
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(remaddr);
    int recvlen;
    int fd;                         // server socket that listens
    int fd_reply;                   // this will be used to reply to all users
    char buf[BUFSIZE];     // receive buffer


    memset((char *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(myaddr));
    myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    myaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if ((fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
        log << "Error: cannot create socket! " << "TIMESTAMP: " << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result)) << endl;
        log.close();
        return 0;
    }

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)) < 0) {
        std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
        log << "Error: bind failed " << "TIMESTAMP: " << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result)) << endl;
        log.close();
        return 0;
    }

    pollfd fds;

    memset(fds, 0, sizeof(fds));

    fds[0].fd = fd;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;

    while (1)
    {
        int rv = poll(ufds, 1, 3500);
        if (rv == -1)
        {
            // error occured
        }
        else if (rv == 0)
        {
            //time out
        }
        else
        {
            //check for events on fd
            if (fds.revents & POLLIN)
            {
                recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remaddr, &addrlen);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes it looks okay.
2. Keep a list of all clients, and then in a loop send to all of them. To populate this list, all clients need to contact the server the first thing they do.

Comment: Small note though - you almost always want to set the sockets to non-blocking mode. In the above code recfrom() can still block for various obscure reasons (e.g. UDP packet fails checksumming, so it's thrown away after poll returns.)

Comment: In my full project, I made a vector that holds all the sockaddr_in for user that "joins" the game.  How would I set the udp socket to nonblocking?

Comment: @kubuni Search for it. There are thousands of examples and tutorials all over the Internet on sockets in generals. Most of them should also show how to make a socket non-blocking for your platform, and how to handle them.